# react-native google translater

Tags: reactjs, reactive-programming, react-native

I have developed an android mobile app using react-native. My native language for the app is English but I want to make it available in Mandarin Chinese also. So my question is how can I convert my static and fetched data into Mandarin Chinese. please share a solution.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can do it.
For changing the Application language to multi-language app,i.e., also include Mandarin Chinese.

1. For Static contents/text Use the package `react-native-i18n`

Link : https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-i18n

2. For Dynamic contents/text use the package `google-translate-api`

Link :https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-translate-api

I18n Example :

```
import I18n from 'react-native-i18n';

class Demo extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <Text>{I18n.t('greeting')}</Text>;
  }
}

// Enable fallbacks if you want `en-US` and `en-GB` to fallback to `en`
I18n.fallbacks = true;

I18n.translations = {
  en: {
    greeting: 'Hi!',
  },
  fr: {
    greeting: 'Bonjour!',
  },
};
```

Google-translator Example:

```
From automatic language detection to English:

const translate = require('google-translate-api');

translate('Ik spreek Engels', {to: 'en'}).then(res => {
    console.log(res.text);
    //=> I speak English
    console.log(res.from.language.iso);
    //=> nl
}).catch(err => {
    console.error(err);
});

From English to Dutch with a typo:

translate('I spea Dutch!', {from: 'en', to: 'nl'}).then(res => {
    console.log(res.text);
    //=> Ik spreek Nederlands!
    console.log(res.from.text.autoCorrected);
    //=> true
    console.log(res.from.text.value);
    //=> I [speak] Dutch!
    console.log(res.from.text.didYouMean);
    //=> false
}).catch(err => {
    console.error(err);
});
```

Hope it helps..!
Thank you

~ Praz

Comment: i18n is working fine but when I am trying google-translate-api I am getting this error:- error: bundling failed: Error: Unable to resolve module `querystring` from `C:\Users\jhon\Desktop\dev\Test123\node_modules\google-translate-api\index.js`: Module `querystring` does
 not exist in the Haste module map

Comment: while importing google-translate-api getting this error:-                                      Error: Unable to resolve module "querystring" from "...". Module "querystring" does not exist in the Haste module map.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue, has anyone found a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to refactor your codebase in some manner.
First of all, if your static data is stored as hardcoded you need to refactor.

I suggest using https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-languages
Example for your inspiration is located [here](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-languages/tree/master/example/).

Now the second part, where you need dynamic translation.

First of all, you need the current user language which is accessible with the beforementioned package.
Then use a package like [google-translate-api](https://github.com/matheuss/google-translate-api) to translate on the fly.

Comment: the package google-translate-api was not maintened, so in 2022 i had to use this fork : https://github.com/AidanWelch/google-translate-api