# Translate dynamic data into multiple language in react native

Tags: react-native, language-translation, dynamic-content

I have developed my app using react native,I need to translate my entire app into user chosen language.

I know translation of the static content.but i need it for dynamic content.
I want to convert the data which is coming from back end API also.So I can't maintain so many j son files related to different languages.

I have already seen below link
[react-native google translater](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53701231/react-native-google-translater)

for static this is working fine
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-i18n

for dynamic i have seen below two npm's which is having installation errors and having issues and not under the maintenance
https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-translate-api

https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-languages

is there any other solution for this?

Comment: have you looked into this [react-native-localize](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-localize)

Comment: yes i have seen..for that npm also they are using json files to convert to specific language ,i can't maintain so many json files .here is the link https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-localize/tree/master/example/android/app/src/main/assets/translations

Answer (score 1):

sir for fast translation of static and dynamic data. you can create one component where you can pass all strings (text) in your app, And use '@aws-sdk/client translate for translation, it's speedy and also works on dynamic data

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-translate/index.html

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@aws-sdk/client-translate